# Getting the position of the point where the user taps on a map

Tags: maps, windows-phone-8.1

How can I get the latitude and longitude of the point where the user taps on a map?

I tried doing this:

```cs
Geocoordinate position = MyMap.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(
        e.GetPosition(MyMap));
```

but I get an error that there's no definition for `ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate`.

Comment: @Xm7X Sorry! Didn't see your edit.

Comment: In 8.1, it's MapControl.GetLocationFromOffset()